# in need of a direct combinatorial/bijective proof

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, enumerative-combinatorics

The following are very familiar and basic items, individually.

(1) The number $a(n)$ of rectangles (parallel to axes) in an $n\times n$ square grid.

(2) The number $b(n)$ of cubes (parallel to axes) in an $n\times n\times n$ cube.

However, I could not find a reference to a direct **bijective** proof for $a(n)=b(n)$. Can you provide such an argument of reference?

Comment: Why do you _need_ such a proof?

Comment: One reason: I plan to generalize to higher dimensions, later.

Comment: Do you have a reason to believe a bijective proof will generalize any more easily than any other (say, algebraic) proof?

Comment: Not necessarily, but it is more elegant if it can be done depending on the construction.

Comment: I think you can cook up a bijective argument using a proof from [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/95055/127263).

Comment: Any specific suggestion?

Comment: I will try to make an answer once I get home.

Comment: Tabulated at https://oeis.org/A000537 – perhaps some of the links and references there would be useful (though I see no mention of cubes in a cube).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following @wojowu's suggestion, we have:

Let $h$ be the side of the inner cube, and let $(i,j,k)$ be its corner nearest the origin.  Then we have $0\le i,j,k < n-h+1 \le n$.

Let us describe our rectangle by the corners $(x_1, y_1)$ and $(x_2, y_2)$ with $x_1<x_2$ and $y_1<y_2$.  Then our mapping from $(i,j,k,h)\to (x_1,y_1), (x_2,y_2)$ looks like

$$ (i,j,k,h) \to
\begin{cases}
(i,k),(j,n-h+1) & \text{if $i<j$} \\
(j,k),(n-h+1,n-h+1) & \text{if $i=j$}\\
(k,j),(n-h+1,i) & \text{if $i>j$}.
\end{cases}
$$

Going the other way we have
$$
(x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2)\to
\begin{cases}
(x_1,x_2,y_1,n-y_2+1) & \text{if $x_2 < y_2$}\\
(x_1,x_1,y_1,n-y_2+1) & \text{if $x_2 = y_2$}\\
(x_2,y_1,x_1,n-y_2+1) & \text{if $x_2 > y_2$}
\end{cases}
$$

It is easy to see that these are inverse.